# How to route ASP.Net Core api return value to appropriate observable based on data type returned

Tags: rxjs, angular7, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created an ASP.NET Core Web Api backend with an Angular 7 frontend. One of the methods in the Api can return either an object or an array to an Angular service. How do I route to specific observable, based on the data type returned? I am a noob to Angular, so any kind assistance would be appreciated.

```
Angular service call to Api:

getLinksFromSitus(situs: any) {
    this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'getLinksFromSitus', situs).subscribe(data =>
    this.apiData.next(data)
    );
  }


Portion of Web Api that returns array if more than one APN present:

// if more than one item in list, get status information for each and return list to user to select appropriate apn
            if (propApn.Count > 1)
            {
                return Ok(propApn);               
            }


Portion of same method to return object if only one value for APN:

var resultsModel = new Results
            {
                ArcGisLink = arcGisLink,
                HistInfoLink = histInfoLink,
                PropInfoLink = propInfoLink          
            };

            return Ok(resultsModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. Typescript can only type things based on static analysis at build time, what your describing would require Typescript to know the result of your API call at build time, which it doesn't do.

The best you can do is indicating that your API call can return both of your them:

```
public myApiFunc(req: MyRequestModel): Observable<any>
```

But that will still require you to figure out which type returned at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution that worked...

```
getLinksFromSitus(situs: any) {
    this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'getLinksFromSitus', situs).subscribe(data => {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty('arcGisLink')) {
      this.apiData.next(data);
    } else {
      let vals = [];
      vals = this.apiPropApn.getValue();
      const item = vals.concat(data);
      this.apiPropApn.next(item);
      }
    });
  }
```

So, after subscribing to the HttpResponse, I am able to check if the data in the response contains a known property. If it doesn't contain the known property, then it concatenates the data to a BehaviorSubject array. It works perfectly.